# Adobe Digital Editions not working

Tags: kobo-glo, adobe-digital-editions

Adobe Digital Editions seems to no longer transfer ebooks to my Kobo Glo (it worked fine in the past).

- I have not changed devices.
- I have not changed versions of Digital Editions.
- I am not getting an error that the transfer failed.

When I start my device, the book I attempted to transfer does not show up.

Comment: Ade is awful - just awful

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried reinstalling Adobe Digital Editions?
Has the version of Adobe Air (needed by Digital Editions) changed? Try reinstalling that as well.
Have you tried transferring with another USB cable?

If none of those options seem to fix the issue, give Calibre a go to manage your ebooks. See if it works with that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried a different computer and it worked???